# How to correctly return User's Text Input with onActivityRequest

Tags: java, android

I am having an issue with a certain lab assignment, The goal is to return a user's text on the screen. However, after looking in the deepest darkest depths of the interweb, I have found no answer.

Here is my code,please tell me how to return User's input

AcitivityLoaderActivity class's code for starting the activity ExplicitlyLoadedActivity:

```
    // TODO - Create a new intent to launch the ExplicitlyLoadedActivity class
    Intent explicitActivity = new Intent(ActivityLoaderActivity.this,ExplicitlyLoadedActivity.class);
    // TODO - Start an Activity using that intent and the request code defined above
    startActivity(explicitActivity);
```

This is the code for receiving the result for User Edit Text

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Entered onActivityResult()");
    // TODO - Process the result only if this method received both a
    // RESULT_OK result code and a recognized request code
    // If so, update the Textview showing the user-entered text.
    if(requestCode==GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE){
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            mUserTextView.setText(data.getStringExtra("givenText"));

        }//end if

    }//end if

}
```

ExplicitlyLoaderActivity class's code:

```
private void enterClicked() {
    final int GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    Log.i(TAG,"Entered enterClicked()");
    // TODO - Save user provided input from the EditText field
    String givenText = mEditText.getText().toString();
    // TODO - Create a new intent and save the input from the EditText field as an extra
    Intent  editText = new Intent();
    editText.putExtra("givenText",givenText);
    // TODO - Set Activity's result with result code RESULT_OK
    setResult(RESULT_OK,editText);
    // TODO - Finish the Activity
    finish();
}
```

Comment: where is your startActivityForResult();

Comment: I did not know I had to add this. Can you explain what that Method does?

Comment: Is **enterClicked()** in AcitivityLoaderActivity???

Comment: if you want the result in onActivityResult from other activity then you have to use startActivityForResult instead of StartActivity

Comment: Piyush: enterClicked is not. It is in a class called ExplicitlyLoadedAcitivty

Comment: What issue do you really have? any logcat content?

Comment: where have you used startActivity post the code?

Comment: I have replaced startActivity(); with startActivityForResult and passed the GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE as a parameter as well and it is working. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AcitivityLoaderActivity class's code:**

use

```
        final int GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
         Intent i=new Intent(AcitivityLoaderActivity.this,ExplicitlyLoadedAcitivty.class);
                 startActivityForResult(i,GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE);
```

**onActivityResult() Method**

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

Log.i(TAG, "Entered onActivityResult()");
// TODO - Process the result only if this method received both a
// RESULT_OK result code and a recognized request code
// If so, update the Textview showing the user-entered text.
if(requestCode==GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE){
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        mUserTextView.setText(data.getStringExtra("givenText"));

    }//end if

}//end if

  }
```

**ExplicitlyLoadedAcitivty**

```
     private void enterClicked() {
final int GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
Log.i(TAG,"Entered enterClicked()");
// TODO - Save user provided input from the EditText field
String givenText = mEditText.getText().toString();
// TODO - Create a new intent and save the input from the EditText field as an extra
Intent  editText = new Intent();
editText.putExtra("givenText",givenText);
// TODO - Set Activity's result with result code RESULT_OK
setResult(RESULT_OK,editText);
// TODO - Finish the Activity
finish();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Entered onActivityResult()");
    // TODO - Process the result only if this method received both a
    // RESULT_OK result code and a recognized request code
    // If so, update the Textview showing the user-entered text.
    if(requestCode==GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE){
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            String editTextString = extras.getString("end_location");

        }//end if

    }//end if

}
```